# rdiff-backup keeps backing up a symlink, ignoring files under it

Tags: linux, backup

I've got a `backup.list` file that looks like this:

```
+ /ext/installs
+ /ext/media
- /ext
- /backup
- /dev
- /mnt
- /proc
```

`/ext` is a symlink to `/mnt/vg1/vol1`, under which are `installs` and `media` directories.

I'm running:

```
rdiff-backup --backup-mode --include-globbing-filelist backup.list / /backup
```

`rdiff-backup` keeps recreating a symlink: `/backup/ext -> /mnt/vg1/vol1`, which is kind of missing the point, because then it doesn't actually back up the files in `/mnt/vg1/vol1/installs`, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. This is how `rdiff-backup` behaves. It copies the symlink file, not the contents it points to, *by design*. If you want /mnt/vg1/vol1 to be backed up you have to add it to your `backup.list` file or tell `rdiff-backup` about it using the `--include` option.

Comment: The problem with that is that `/ext` already moved once (from `/mnt/vg0/vol1`). I wanted to use symlinks to hide this from everyone (including rdiff-backup). If I `--include` it by fully-qualifying the paths, I'll end up with two copies of the source files (one new, pristine; one old, under increments).

Comment: Wish I had a better answer for you but: that's life with rsdiff-backup.

Instead of making /ext a symlink, could you not mount /mnt/vg0/vol1 at /ext? That would solve the problem.